# Please explain this line of js code.

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code block, and is not very clear about it:

```
var level = this.getLevelForResolution(this.map.getResolution());
var coef = 360 / Math.pow(2, level);

var x_num = this.topTileFromX < this.topTileToX ? Math.round((bounds.left - this.topTileFromX) / coef) : Math.round((this.topTileFromX - bounds.right) / coef);
var y_num = this.topTileFromY < this.topTileToY ? Math.round((bounds.bottom - this.topTileFromY) / coef) : Math.round((this.topTileFromY - bounds.top) / coef);
```

What does the `<` in `this.topTileFromX <` mean?

Comment: "<" is the less than sign in the condition of a ternary operator. Beyond that, the question isn't very clear.

Comment: @TimMedora, I think he has difficulties in expressing in English. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: thanks. my language is not english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a JavaScript Ternary operator. See [Details Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

```
var x_num = this.topTileFromX < this.topTileToX ? Math.round((bounds.left - this.topTileFromX) / coef) : Math.round((this.topTileFromX - bounds.right) / coef);
```

is equivalent to the following expression

```
var x_num;

if (this.topTileFromX < this.topTileToX )
{
    x_num= Math.round((bounds.left - this.topTileFromX) / coef);
}
else
{
    x_num= Math.round((this.topTileFromX - bounds.right) / coef);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<` means "lesser than", like in Mathematics.

Thus

- `2 < 3` returns `true`
- `2 < 2` is `false`
- `3 < 2` is also `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
var x_num = this.topTileFromX < this.topTileToX ? Math.round((bounds.left - this.topTileFromX) / coef) : Math.round((this.topTileFromX - bounds.right) / coef);
```

It's a shorter if statement. It means:

```
var x_num;

if(this.topTileFromX < this.topTileToX)
{
   x_num = Math.round((bounds.left - this.topTileFromX) / coef);
}
else
{
   x_num = Math.round((this.topTileFromX - bounds.right) / coef);
}
```